# Drop the duplicate of a certain column when there are many duplicate columns

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a dataframe with multiple duplicate columns but I would like to drop the duplicate of the "class" column while keeping other duplicate columns intact. Below you can see there are many duplicate columns. However, I am only interested in dropping the "class" column and keep one copy of it only. The other columns should stay intact and row number should not change.

Dataframe:

```py
train = pd.DataFrame({'class': {0: 1,
  1: 2,
  2: 3,
  3: 4,
  4: 5,
  5: 6,
  6: 7,
  7: 8,
  8: 1,
  9: 2,
  10: 3,
  11: 4,
  12: 5,
  13: 6,
  14: 7,
  15: 8},
 'class.1': {0: 1,
  1: 2,
  2: 3,
  3: 4,
  4: 5,
  5: 6,
  6: 7,
  7: 8,
  8: 1,
  9: 2,
  10: 3,
  11: 4,
  12: 5,
  13: 6,
  14: 7,
  15: 8},
 'class.2': {0: 1,
  1: 2,
  2: 3,
  3: 4,
  4: 5,
  5: 6,
  6: 7,
  7: 8,
  8: 1,
  9: 2,
  10: 3,
  11: 4,
  12: 5,
  13: 6,
  14: 7,
  15: 8},
 'x_feature_1': {0: -0.30424321,
  1: 1.6273111,
  2: 0.66127653,
  3: 0.0051847840000000004,
  4: 1.2861978,
  5: -0.47925246,
  6: 1.4743277,
  7: 0.30530296,
  8: -0.30424321,
  9: 1.6273111,
  10: 0.66127653,
  11: 0.0051847840000000004,
  12: 1.2861978,
  13: -0.47925246,
  14: 1.4743277,
  15: 0.30530296},
 'x_feature_1.1': {0: -0.30424321,
  1: 1.6273111,
  2: 0.66127653,
  3: 0.0051847840000000004,
  4: 1.2861978,
  5: -0.47925246,
  6: 1.4743277,
  7: 0.30530296,
  8: -0.30424321,
  9: 1.6273111,
  10: 0.66127653,
  11: 0.0051847840000000004,
  12: 1.2861978,
  13: -0.47925246,
  14: 1.4743277,
  15: 0.30530296},
 'x_feature_2': {0: -0.30424321,
  1: 1.6273111,
  2: 0.66127653,
  3: 0.0051847840000000004,
  4: 1.2861978,
  5: -0.47925246,
  6: 1.4743277,
  7: 0.30530296,
  8: -0.30424321,
  9: 1.6273111,
  10: 0.66127653,
  11: 0.0051847840000000004,
  12: 1.2861978,
  13: -0.47925246,
  14: 1.4743277,
  15: 0.30530296},
 'y_feature_1': {0: -0.30424321,
  1: 1.6273111,
  2: 0.66127653,
  3: 0.0051847840000000004,
  4: 1.2861978,
  5: -0.47925246,
  6: 1.4743277,
  7: 0.30530296,
  8: -0.30424321,
  9: 1.6273111,
  10: 0.66127653,
  11: 0.0051847840000000004,
  12: 1.2861978,
  13: -0.47925246,
  14: 1.4743277,
  15: 0.30530296},
 'y_feature_2': {0: -0.30424321,
  1: 1.6273111,
  2: 0.66127653,
  3: 0.0051847840000000004,
  4: 1.2861978,
  5: -0.47925246,
  6: 1.4743277,
  7: 0.30530296,
  8: -0.30424321,
  9: 1.6273111,
  10: 0.66127653,
  11: 0.0051847840000000004,
  12: 1.2861978,
  13: -0.47925246,
  14: 1.4743277,
  15: 0.30530296},
 'y_feature_2.1': {0: -0.30424321,
  1: 1.6273111,
  2: 0.66127653,
  3: 0.0051847840000000004,
  4: 1.2861978,
  5: -0.47925246,
  6: 1.4743277,
  7: 0.30530296,
  8: -0.30424321,
  9: 1.6273111,
  10: 0.66127653,
  11: 0.0051847840000000004,
  12: 1.2861978,
  13: -0.47925246,
  14: 1.4743277,
  15: 0.30530296},
 'z_feature_1': {0: -0.30424321,
  1: 1.6273111,
  2: 0.66127653,
  3: 0.0051847840000000004,
  4: 1.2861978,
  5: -0.47925246,
  6: 1.4743277,
  7: 0.30530296,
  8: -0.30424321,
  9: 1.6273111,
  10: 0.66127653,
  11: 0.0051847840000000004,
  12: 1.2861978,
  13: -0.47925246,
  14: 1.4743277,
  15: 0.30530296},
 'z_feature_1.1': {0: -0.30424321,
  1: 1.6273111,
  2: 0.66127653,
  3: 0.0051847840000000004,
  4: 1.2861978,
  5: -0.47925246,
  6: 1.4743277,
  7: 0.30530296,
  8: -0.30424321,
  9: 1.6273111,
  10: 0.66127653,
  11: 0.0051847840000000004,
  12: 1.2861978,
  13: -0.47925246,
  14: 1.4743277,
  15: 0.30530296},
 'z_feature_2': {0: -0.30424321,
  1: 1.6273111,
  2: 0.66127653,
  3: 0.0051847840000000004,
  4: 1.2861978,
  5: -0.47925246,
  6: 1.4743277,
  7: 0.30530296,
  8: -0.30424321,
  9: 1.6273111,
  10: 0.66127653,
  11: 0.0051847840000000004,
  12: 1.2861978,
  13: -0.47925246,
  14: 1.4743277,
  15: 0.30530296}})
```

expected:

```py
expected = pd.DataFrame({'class': {0: 1,
  1: 2,
  2: 3,
  3: 4,
  4: 5,
  5: 6,
  6: 7,
  7: 8,
  8: 1,
  9: 2,
  10: 3,
  11: 4,
  12: 5,
  13: 6,
  14: 7,
  15: 8},
 'x_feature_1': {0: -0.30424321,
  1: 1.6273111,
  2: 0.66127653,
  3: 0.0051847840000000004,
  4: 1.2861978,
  5: -0.47925246,
  6: 1.4743277,
  7: 0.30530296,
  8: -0.30424321,
  9: 1.6273111,
  10: 0.66127653,
  11: 0.0051847840000000004,
  12: 1.2861978,
  13: -0.47925246,
  14: 1.4743277,
  15: 0.30530296},
 'x_feature_1.1': {0: -0.30424321,
  1: 1.6273111,
  2: 0.66127653,
  3: 0.0051847840000000004,
  4: 1.2861978,
  5: -0.47925246,
  6: 1.4743277,
  7: 0.30530296,
  8: -0.30424321,
  9: 1.6273111,
  10: 0.66127653,
  11: 0.0051847840000000004,
  12: 1.2861978,
  13: -0.47925246,
  14: 1.4743277,
  15: 0.30530296},
 'x_feature_2': {0: -0.30424321,
  1: 1.6273111,
  2: 0.66127653,
  3: 0.0051847840000000004,
  4: 1.2861978,
  5: -0.47925246,
  6: 1.4743277,
  7: 0.30530296,
  8: -0.30424321,
  9: 1.6273111,
  10: 0.66127653,
  11: 0.0051847840000000004,
  12: 1.2861978,
  13: -0.47925246,
  14: 1.4743277,
  15: 0.30530296},
 'y_feature_1': {0: -0.30424321,
  1: 1.6273111,
  2: 0.66127653,
  3: 0.0051847840000000004,
  4: 1.2861978,
  5: -0.47925246,
  6: 1.4743277,
  7: 0.30530296,
  8: -0.30424321,
  9: 1.6273111,
  10: 0.66127653,
  11: 0.0051847840000000004,
  12: 1.2861978,
  13: -0.47925246,
  14: 1.4743277,
  15: 0.30530296},
 'y_feature_2': {0: -0.30424321,
  1: 1.6273111,
  2: 0.66127653,
  3: 0.0051847840000000004,
  4: 1.2861978,
  5: -0.47925246,
  6: 1.4743277,
  7: 0.30530296,
  8: -0.30424321,
  9: 1.6273111,
  10: 0.66127653,
  11: 0.0051847840000000004,
  12: 1.2861978,
  13: -0.47925246,
  14: 1.4743277,
  15: 0.30530296},
 'y_feature_2.1': {0: -0.30424321,
  1: 1.6273111,
  2: 0.66127653,
  3: 0.0051847840000000004,
  4: 1.2861978,
  5: -0.47925246,
  6: 1.4743277,
  7: 0.30530296,
  8: -0.30424321,
  9: 1.6273111,
  10: 0.66127653,
  11: 0.0051847840000000004,
  12: 1.2861978,
  13: -0.47925246,
  14: 1.4743277,
  15: 0.30530296},
 'z_feature_1': {0: -0.30424321,
  1: 1.6273111,
  2: 0.66127653,
  3: 0.0051847840000000004,
  4: 1.2861978,
  5: -0.47925246,
  6: 1.4743277,
  7: 0.30530296,
  8: -0.30424321,
  9: 1.6273111,
  10: 0.66127653,
  11: 0.0051847840000000004,
  12: 1.2861978,
  13: -0.47925246,
  14: 1.4743277,
  15: 0.30530296},
 'z_feature_1.1': {0: -0.30424321,
  1: 1.6273111,
  2: 0.66127653,
  3: 0.0051847840000000004,
  4: 1.2861978,
  5: -0.47925246,
  6: 1.4743277,
  7: 0.30530296,
  8: -0.30424321,
  9: 1.6273111,
  10: 0.66127653,
  11: 0.0051847840000000004,
  12: 1.2861978,
  13: -0.47925246,
  14: 1.4743277,
  15: 0.30530296},
 'z_feature_2': {0: -0.30424321,
  1: 1.6273111,
  2: 0.66127653,
  3: 0.0051847840000000004,
  4: 1.2861978,
  5: -0.47925246,
  6: 1.4743277,
  7: 0.30530296,
  8: -0.30424321,
  9: 1.6273111,
  10: 0.66127653,
  11: 0.0051847840000000004,
  12: 1.2861978,
  13: -0.47925246,
  14: 1.4743277,
  15: 0.30530296}})
```

[in]:

```py
train = train.loc[:,~(train["class"].duplicated())]
```

[out]:

```
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).
```

Edit: Added example dataframe and expected output dataframe.

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates('class')`

Comment: Omit `:` because it filter by columns and also `loc` is not necessary like:

    `train = train[~train["class"].duplicated()]`

Comment: @Erfan - yop, you are right

Comment: @jezrael these solutions shorten the dataframe somehow it dropped from 896 rows to 8 rows. I think they deleted the dupplicate rows in term of class

Comment: @moli - can you add some sample data and expected output?

Comment: @jezrael Edited the question to include an example dataframe

Comment: @moli - answer was edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match not duplicated column with values before `.` with `split` and chaining mask by select columns starting by `class`:

```
m1 = train.columns.str.startswith('class')
m2 = train.columns.str.split('.').str[0].duplicated()
train = train.loc[:, ~m1 | ~m2]
print (train)
```

Comment: How is this not a duplicate?